# How can I unit test my FluentMigrator migrations?

Tags: unit-testing, fluent-migrator

The general advice is I should always test my database migrations, but how to do it seems to be a well kept secret ;)

My chosen framework is FluentMigration.

What I think I want to do is:

1. Migrate database to N-1.
2. Save some data.
3. Migrate database to N.
4. Read data and verify it's not lost.
5. Verify other relevant changes

But I can't figure out how to run the migrations from my unit tests.

Comment: This is very much an integration test and not a unit test. If you were to mock the database then the tests would be pretty pointless. But that's just a minor quibble ;-) Richard's answer is what you need. Are you going to test the down migrations as well? They're the ones that usually contains bugs as you notice straight away if the up migrations don't work.

Comment: I tend to use the term 'unit test' whenever I use a unit testing framework. I'm not sure I'd this an integration test, even if it fits the definition; it has really nothing to do with integration. But I agree, this is a minor quibble.

Comment: Good point, btw, to test the down migrations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To kick off the migration in your integration tests just shell out to the migrate.exe command using Process.Start

For example

```
var migrator = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("migrator.exe", "/connection \"Data Source=db\\db.sqlite;Version=3;\" /db sqlite /target your.migrations.dll");
migrator.WaitForExit();
```

If you're using MSTest you'll have to make sure that migrator.exe is included as a deployment item, or that you specify a path to where the .exe lives when you start the process.

Comment: In my opinion, using deployment items is a bad habit. But even if I don't use MSTest, I have to make sure the .exe is copied to the bin-folder? Or specify the path?

Comment: If you use xUnit or similar just include the full path for the migrator exe